# Background color of the button is not changing through tab key selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

**When I hover on the button through mouse pointer the background color is changing, but through the tab key background color is not changing.**

**In html**

```
<style>
    .btn-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #227ab9;  
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .BtnStyle {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary:active{
        background-color: #1a5e8e;

    }
</style>    

<table>
    <td><input id="txt" class="" type="text" value=""></td>
    <td id="go" class="BtnStyle btn-primary" >
        <button class="btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-chevron-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>test</button>
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine may be the problem is with the colors

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .btn-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #227ab9;  
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .BtnStyle {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary:active{
        background-color: #1a5e8e;

    }
</style>    

<table>
    <td><input id="txt" class="" type="text" value=""></td>
    <td id="go" class="BtnStyle btn-primary" >
        <button class="btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-chevron-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>test</button>
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: can you summarize your change in words?

Comment: no it just for test because icon is not loaded in my site then how can i check

Comment: instead of <button class="btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-chevron-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>test</button>  specify <button class="btn-primary">test</button>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me! Please take a look at below code.

Or if you are still having a problem please share your full code in jsFiddle.

Take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/pratik_shah/pen/QbrqyJ)

```
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #227ab9;  
}
.BtnStyle {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
 .btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary:active{
    background-color: red;// #1a5e8e;

}


<table>
    <td><input id="txt" class="" type="text" value=""></td>
    <td id="go" class="BtnStyle btn-primary" >
                <button class="btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-chevron-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Button</button>
   </td>
</table>
```